# what could make examined_rows change radically?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have a mysql-based application which sometimes takes forever to execute a select statement. When this happens, the statement appears naturally in my slow query log:

```
# Query_time: 51.826420  Lock_time: 0.000143 Rows_sent: 3  Rows_examined: 15574557
```

Rows examined above tells me that a full table scan occured. However, normally, the same query examines at least one order of magnitude less rows. Namely, performance_schema.events_statements_history tells me exactly 982937. Naturally, the execution time for this query is one order of magnitude smaller in this case.

I checked that explain on this query appears to give the same result in both cases. I also checked that if I add a USE INDEX statement when this problem occurs, the execution time goes down back to normal but, normally, I do not need to add the USE INDEX.

One of the queries that exhibit this behavior is shown below:

```
SELECT     
     COUNT(DISTINCT(t.id)),
     t.tag_3 AS group_0 
FROM
     tasks AS t
WHERE
         t.message_time >= FROM_UNIXTIME(1486508400)
     AND t.message_time  < FROM_UNIXTIME(1487113200)
     AND (   (t.type = 12 AND t.site_id = 172)
          OR (t.type = 1  AND t.site_id = 172)
          OR (t.type = 8  AND t.site_id = 173) )
     AND t.tag_1 IN (74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,99,263)
     AND t.tag_3 IN (302,303,305)
     AND t.tag_4 IN (315,316,317,318,319,320,321,322,323,351,352,357)
     AND t.site_id IN (172,173)
GROUP BY
     group_0;
```

The explain output:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                                                         | key      | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | range | IX_site_id,IX_site_id_type,IX_tag_1,IX_tag_3,IX_tag_4,IX_message_time | IX_tag_4 | 5       | NULL | 24732 | Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

All tables use innodb engines.

What could trigger such different behaviours at different points in time ? Namely, what could have caused a full table scan ?

Comment: Could be inaccurate index stats. Optimize the table and try again.

Comment: I did. It did not change.

Comment: You might need to add the query and/or execution plan. There are too many possible reasons why your query might behave differently. Since you say that it has the same execution plan, another explanation is often the data content. E.g. `select * from table where some_unindexed_column = 5 limit 10` can be very fast if you have a lot of `5`'s in your data, but will required a full table scan if only 9 rows contain a `5`. Since in your query, you only get 3 rows, it might be an unfulfilled limit here too, so compare that number to your fast query.

Comment: @Solarflare, that is a good point. There is no limit in my query though. I have added a testcase that exhibits this behavior as well as the explain output.

Comment: Are you sure you get the same execution plan (=the same index)? Which `use index` improves it? The right index depend heavily on your actual data. If you e.g. have only one row that matches `tag_4 IN (...)`, but 2 million rows with `tag_3 = 302`, the index on `tag_4` is better than the one on `tag_3`. But different `IN (...)`-lists in the next query can change that completely. MySQL (and you and I) has to guess there a lot. Without further knowledge about your data, I would probably use an index `(tag_3, message_time)`, maybe with additional columns, and not use `ix_tag_4` for this `IN`.

Comment: @Solarflare, I agree completely about the fact that which index is chosen will result in fairly different performance. Because I know my data, I would probably pick IX_site_id myself but, I think that this is not really an issue. i.e., regardless of which index is chosen, the execution time as well as the number of rows_examined is fairly small (smaller than 5s and 1M respectively) . What I have observed in the slow query log is rows_examined = 15M which is more or less the size of the table which tells me the thing is doing a full table scan.

Comment: I should add that I do not have an exact log of the execution plan that was displayed when I ran this query on the live system exhibiting the problem so, I can't say with 100% confidence that the explain output was _exactly_ the same it is now.

Comment: @Solarflare Ok, I believe you are entirely right. I did double-check executing the same query with a different use index() hint, once for each index and yes, I can see that _some_ indexes lead to a full table scan (IX_tag_1 and IX_tag_2 at least)

Comment: @Solarflare feel free to add an answer so I can accept it. Thanks for your help !

Comment: The slowlog's `Rows_examined` is exact.  Explain's and Show table status's `Rows` are estimates.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening -- The Optimizer picked a different way to perform the query.

You are at the whim of

- The Optimizer -- It gets better with each new version.
- The statistics -- `ANALYZE TABLE` *may* help, or *could* hurt.  (`OPTIMIZE` is overkill, and ends with `ANALYZE`; "never" use it.)
- The constants in the query -- May lead the optimizer to pick a different explain plan.
- The "phase of the moon", as I call this combination of whims.

If `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` and there is no `JOIN`, you are asking for a lot of extra work: `COUNT(DISTINCT(t.id)),`; switch to simply `COUNT(*)`.

When a query is *run*, some `EXPLAIN` plan is generated.
When you use `EXPLAIN`, a plan is generated.
There is no guarantee that they match.  (This is solved only in the latest version, wherein the `EXPLAIN` is optionally included in the slowlog.

Any single-column index on any of these *may* be best; there is no way to know without a lot more info on the distribution of the data:  tag_1, tag_3, tag_4, site_id, message_time.  I would have several 2-col "composite" indexes starting with each and ending with message_time.  This way, if the query actually says `foo IN (just-one-item)`, it can move past `foo` and also use `message_time`.

Before discussing further, please add `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.